# Apex Batch - Is execute method called if start returns 0 results?

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I want to know if the execute method in a batch is still called if the query in start() returns 0 records.

I put debugs in the beginning of the execute method, I know start will not return any records but i still need execute to fire.

I'm I on a fool's errand?

Comment: Why not put the logic that must run in the `finish` method then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Execute will not be called unless at least one [non-null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47856) item is available for processing. You'll have to come up with an alternative method. As a corollary to this statement, "scope" will never be empty or null, because execute won't be called if there's nothing to do.