# Under what conditions does the Execute method in a batch class not get called

Tags: apex

I am under the suspicion that the execute method in a batch apex class does not get called when the scope is null. Is this true? When the scope returns null I still want the execute method to be called.

Answer (score 6):

The `execute()` method will not be called if your `start` method returns either `null` or an empty iterable. So for example if you implement `Database.Batchable<sObject>` and your `Database.getQueryLocator(query)` returns an empty result set, the `execute()` method will not run.

Comment: +1, though, in simpler terms, "execute will not run if there's nothing to do."

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox for a much more eloquent explanation :)

Comment: @sfdcfox Can I force it to run?

Comment: No, but you can move the logic currently into your `execute()` method to another Apex Class, and then in your batch `start()` method, if you can determine that your query or your iterable collection will be empty, then you can call that other Apex class

Comment: I'm getting this error when returning null from start() method, "System.UnexpectedException: Start did not return a valid iterable object." would you please clarify how to return null from start() in order to avoid execute() from being called but still let finish() to run thanks! Happy New Year! 

Comment: @Bahman.A you would not return null. Just an empty iterable object.

Comment: What about a Database.quaeyLocatore type? Is it a bad practice to return a query that we know doesn’t find any records and returns empty lost, for example records with createdDate > TOMORROW? I tried it and it works but don’t know if it’s the best way to do this. Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 2):

The system will never run an execute method if there's nothing to run. Also be aware that null values are [stripped from the list of elements to process](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/47856/2984). As a workaround, you could consider using a Wrapper class and returning at least one value. For example:

```
public Wrapper[] start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    Wrapper[] results = new Wrapper[0];
    Wrapper temp = new Wrapper();
    for(sObject record: ...) {
        temp.records.add(record);
        if(temp.records.size() == 100) {
            results.add(temp);
            temp = new Wrapper();
        }
    }
    // add the last (partial) batch
    results.add(temp);
    return results;
}
```

At this point, you've constructed the code in a way that will force at least one iteration of execute, even if there's nothing to do.

However, this solution won't work if you expect you may get more than 50,000 records. You might also be able to use a hybrid solution by returning `Iterable<Object>` and use a Wrapper if there's less than X records, or a `Database.QueryLocator` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a query locator implementation, you could force execute to be run once by ensuring start:

1. Runs the exact same query WHERE against the same object but as a COUNT.
2. If the count is 0 then explicitly call execute with an empty scope
3. Return the required query locator

This only consumes one additional query per batch execution, and one additional row in start (which is not relevant to the limits applied when execute is called anyway since start/execute/finish are called in different transactions).

Comment: You mean call execute with empty scope?

Comment: Yes, accidental mention of "start". Corrected. Thanks.